# How to start ASP.Net State Service in Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, session-state, stateserver

While deploying my application in azure i got this error when a session variable is used

[image]

I know this error is due to `ASP.Net state server mode`. I started the service in my local PC but how to start this service in `Azure` environment?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [start up task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) to spin up the State Service (or really any service for that matter). However, I would highly recommend that you do not use the session state service.  I'd recommend looking at the [In Role Windows Azure Cache](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-in-role-cache/) or the [Windows Azure Cache Service (Preview)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386094.aspx/#sectionSection0) for session state.

By using the session service you separate your session concerns from your web servers.  It is still in preview, so if that concerns you, look at the In Role cache, which won't cost any more to run and can be distributed across multiple machines.  Also, if you think the latency to pull from the cache service will be too high then the InRole cache may turn out to be better for you (you'd have to test to be sure).

Comment: Use InRole cache if you're using Cloud Service Web Roles, it's cheaper and faster. If you're using Web Sites the latency difference between the cache service and an InRole cache running on dedicated worker roles is negligible.

Comment: +1 Thanks for reply. I am not using Azure web and server roles and I am on trial version so Cache is not enabled in that

Comment: What to do if i am using ASp.Net MVC and state server?

Comment: Never try in Azure, but please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278339.aspx. Maybe it help

Comment: Looks like In Role Windows Azure Cache and Windows Azure Cache Service have been discontinued and that the answer should be updated to ASP.NET Session State Provider for Azure Redis Cache https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-aspnet-session-state-provider

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the session objects are not serializable (SpreadSheetGear objects). If I use IIS load balancer (which also has ARR), then the requests will hit the same server anyway. So I don't see what I shouldn't use it. What I wonder is: once I startup the State Server by a task, how can I tell the IIS running in the VM box to use that?

Comment: Configure it like you would on premise in the web.config. However, you shouldn't in Azure, because Azure might move or recycle your instance at any time, invalidating your sessions.