# How to execute appcmd on Azure Web App box?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service, session-state-server

I'd like to execute a

```
appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:sessionState /mode:StateServer /stateConnectionString: tcpip=loopback:42424 /stateNetworkTimeout: 120 /useHostingIdentity:True
```

command on the box belonging to an Azure Web App. The console is a "sandbox environment", so I don't necessarily expect to have enough privileges, but `appcmd` is not recognized as a command.

Same thing happened with the KUDU special console - which looked more promising in terms of potential privileges to carry out the task -, both with the CMD and the PowerShell console.

My main goal is to start the IIS's State Server. [How to start ASP.Net State Service in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508051/how-to-start-asp-net-state-service-in-azure) mentions "startup task", but I couldn't figure out how to do that. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412(v=ws.10).aspx quotes `appcmd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your link in your question: Startup tasks are for web/worker roles in Cloud Services, not Web Apps (completely different things; web/worker role instances are Windows Server instances, not a sandboxed environment).

You cannot enable IIS State Server on Web Apps. You'll need to store your session state in something like Redis Cache service, which runs independent of Azure Web Apps. Really, you can use any cache (or storage) you want that's external to the Web App sandbox, as long as you have proper drivers/providers for what you choose.

Comment: I thought the tasks are for roles. What's the technical reason the State Server cannot be enabled? If my session state were serializable I wouldn't bring this SO Question up and went with the Redis cache right away. I wish I could use it.

Comment: Yes, startup tasks are specifically for roles (worker roles and web roles). You stated you're deploying to Web Apps, which is completely different from web/worker roles, and has no such concept.

Comment: Right, thanks. Do you know the technical reason behind the State Server cannot be enabled?

Comment: I realized that State Server doesn't help me anyway, that requires serialization of the cached objects just like any other out of proc cache provider.